# How to share ignore.conf using shared configuration repository in PlasticSCM?

Tags: version-control, plasticscm

Is it possible to share the ignore.conf with all clients via the shared configuration repository **plastic-global-config** ? I can't seem to find any documentation regarding that special repo except for custom extension configurations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "client.conf" is a client side configuration file. The user-global ignore file is a file that affects to all the machine workspaces and not only a specific one.

But as a client config file, if you want to share this file with the different Plastic users, I would recommend you to commit it into your repository. This way all the developers will be able to download it. If you prefer, to independently customize the ignored files, keep it as private (local not committed file).

Comment: Thanks! so to confirm, there is not a way to pre-define ignore rules for all users of a repo server. correct?